# Flag column if row within a time period of a previous row

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe (300 million rows) that includes patient's initial hospital stays as well as any readmits for that patient. I need to identify the readmits. The dataframe is grouped by patient ids (Key) and sorted by Key then 'admit' date ascending. There are two conditions to identify a readmit:

First condition - Num1 for the row being tested must be a value between 10-15.

Second Condition - the admit date of the row must fall between the discharge and 90DayPostDischarge date of a previous row. The caveat to the second rule is that there could be multiple initial hospital stays for a patient. These initial stays would be identified by being separated by more than 90 days from the initial stay. An example of this situation is in the results for Key 10003: index 0 and 2 are both initial hospital stays.

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['10003', '10003', '10003', '10003', '10003','10034','10034', '10034'], 
               'Num1': [13,13,13,13,13,13,16,13],
               'Num2': [121,122,122,124,125,126,127,128],
              'admit': [20120506, 20120511, 20121010,20121015,20121020,20120510,20120516,20120520],
          'discharge': [20120510, 20120515, 20121012,20121016,20121023,20120515,20120518,20120522]})
df['admit'] = pd.to_datetime(df['admit'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['discharge'] = pd.to_datetime(df['discharge'], format='%Y%m%d')
df['90DayPostDischarge'] = df['discharge'] + timedelta(days=90)
df
```

Initial df:

```
    Key     Num1    Num2    admit       discharge   90DayPostDischarge
0   10003   13      121     2012-05-06  2012-05-10  2012-08-08
1   10003   13      122     2012-05-11  2012-05-15  2012-08-13
2   10003   13      122     2012-10-10  2012-10-12  2013-01-10
3   10003   13      124     2012-10-15  2012-10-16  2013-01-14
4   10003   13      125     2012-10-20  2012-10-23  2013-01-21
5   10034   13      126     2012-05-10  2012-05-15  2012-08-13
6   10034   16      127     2012-05-16  2012-05-18  2012-08-16
7   10034   13      128     2012-05-20  2012-05-22  2012-08-20
```

Final Result:

```
    Key     Num1    Num2    admit       discharge   90DayPostDischarge Readmit
0   10003   13      121     2012-05-06  2012-05-10  2012-08-08         0        #the first row of every group will be false(0) as it cannot be compared to the previous rows
1   10003   13      122     2012-05-11  2012-05-15  2012-08-13         1        #this qualifies as a readmit to the previous row
2   10003   13      122     2012-10-10  2012-10-12  2013-01-10         0        #this is the same patient but because this row is outside of the previous date ranges, it will be considered a new initial stay
3   10003   13      124     2012-10-15  2012-10-16  2013-01-14         1        #this will be flagged as a readmit to the previous row
4   10003   13      125     2012-10-20  2012-10-23  2013-01-21         1        #this too will be a readmit FOR THE INITIAL STAY AT INDEX 2
5   10034   13      126     2012-05-10  2012-05-15  2012-08-13         0        #the first row of every group will be false(0) as it cannot be compared to the previous rows
6   10034   16      127     2012-05-16  2012-05-18  2012-08-16         0        #this row has a num1 value that is out of the range of 10-15 so it will be flagged as false(0)
7   10034   13      128     2012-05-20  2012-05-22  2012-08-20         1        #this will be flagged as true(1) because of index 5
```

My attempt: I first remove all rows that don't qualify based on the first condition (I realize that making a new df is probably not the best approach. Working on fixing this). Second I attempt to flag rows that may fall into the 2nd condition, however my code is just returning a single value of 'true' and not a df with the flagged column. I'm having a brain fart this approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
df2 = df[df['Num1'].isin([10,11,12,13,14,15])]
df2 = df.loc[((df['admit'] > df['discharge'].shift(1)) & \
                  (df['admit'] <= df['90DayPostDischarge'].shift(1))),'readmit'] = 'true'
```